# Bootstrap 4 list-group-item overlapping borders

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `list-group` with 10 items in it. The second and second to last item always have thicker bottom border's than the rest, no matter what data is inside them. I believe this is caused by the `margin-bottom: -1px` that bootstrap uses by default not working properly.

You can see here with the following JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/4gdcgf4t/

I am using no extra CSS besides the bootstrap CDN. Why could this be happening?

Comment: What browser are you using? It looks right in Chrome and IE 11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The second and second to last item always have thicker bottom border's than the rest, no matter what data is inside them.

That's not true in any browser I tested with: (Chrome, FF, IE, Edge).

I suggest you press `Ctrl`+`0` and reset your zoom level.

Comment: Looks like it happens at 90% zoom (for his particular issue)

Comment: I was at 90% zoom, switching to 100% zoom fixes the issue. Is there a reason this would affect only some of the `list-group-item`'s?

Comment: @JasonHeine: I was unsure if I should post it as an answer or try to stick it inside a comment. I realized it might be helpful to others, not only to OP, so decided to go for the answer.

Comment: @BlakeThomson: browser zoom generates decimal pixels. They get rounded. If you put 200 items in your list, you might observe a pattern.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu No, this is the answer, and not a comment. While it is an easy answer for this situation, it's the solution :)